# TemplateSyntaxError whenever I try to use a filter in my templates

Tags: django, django-templates

testlist is just a list of objects. For example

```
testlist.0.name
```

is simply "Test3"

I have a file temp.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{{testlist.0.name | safe}}
{% endblock %}
```

that's all there is in the temp.html file and base.html works fine with all other html files that use it

temp.html gives me

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /mytests/
Could not parse the remainder: ' | safe' from 'testlist.0.name | safe'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/mytests/
Django Version: 1.4
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Could not parse the remainder: ' | safe' from 'testlist.0.name | safe'
```

when I change it to:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{{testlist.0.lastedited |date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" }} 
{% endblock %}
```

it gives me

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /mytests/
could not parse some characters: testlist.0.lastedited| ||date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT"
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/mytests/
Django Version: 1.4
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Could not parse some characters: testlist.0.lastedited| ||date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT"
```

you get the idea. It seems that I just cannot use any filters in my django templates.  I tried other filters and still get the same thing.
Am I missing some options that enable the use of the pipe character? Can it be that the "|" key on my macbook pro is not the pipe character but some other character that django fails to recognise?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you need to remove your whitespace between your `testlist.0.lastedited` and filter. Try something like:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{{testlist.0.name|safe}}
{% endblock %}
```

I'm guessing this is your problem, since in the docs, they don't have any whitespace, and they parse the template as a string or something close to it, so whitespace can affect it.

[Template example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/templates/#templates)

Comment: Ok, just figured out how to do that, thanks again. I'm new at this :)